# Profile link lost its linkiness!

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks

I just noticed [Andrew Barber's sock puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788622/some-arbitrary-user). Along with it, I noticed this:

[image]

It seems the system isn't recognizing the link as a link. What gives?

Comment: The account does not have enough reputation for links to show up as links.

Comment: And stop stalking my sock puppet ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber, you have fan following :P